# How to use the same hierarchy for two different cascading parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, mdx, hierarchy, cube

I am building an SSRS report using a cube. I would like to add two parameters, so that they cascade. I would like to use the same Dimension AND hierarchy for both parameters.

For example, if I have **Person > Department > Domain > Unit**, then I would like the first parameter to have Domain be the values. Then when the user makes a selection for the first parameter, I would like the second parameter to have results filtered based on the first selection. So after the user chooses a Domain, then they can pick a Unit, and these units would be filtered based on the Domain selection.

The problem is that when I try to set up the second parameter, the Department hierarchy is not available, and this is an issue because Unit is under the same hierarchy. I can only provide a hierarchy once for a parameter, then after it is not an available option to choose in Query Designer for a second parameter.

Does any one know why this is or a work around. I am okay with MDX if there are some custom solutions for this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give a default value while building the "months". So instead of passing the fully qualified member name in `SSRS`, pass only the member value and build the rest of it in the query.

```
StrToSet("[Accident Date].[Year-Quarter-Month-Date].&[" + @months+ "]")
```

So you pass the parameter as a literal string like below.

[image]

I suggest, you do the same for all other date related parameters so that you don't run into this issue.

For the dataset corresponding to the "months" parameter, have the MDX like below:

```
SELECT [Measures].[SomeMeasure] on 0,
[Date].[Y-Q-M-D].[Month].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM (
        SELECT StrToSet("[Date].[Y-Q-M-D].&[" + @year + "]") ON 0 
        FROM [SomeCube]
     )
```

Map the month column to the `@months`'s value in parameter properties.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a quick look at the SSRS Query Designer for MDX, and it's dreadful.  It makes decisions about the underlying MDX code for you, and it's very difficult (if not impossible) to actually edit the raw MDX.

Have you tried this [workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328234/can-not-edit-mdx-queries-in-query-designer-of-ssrs-for-ssas-data-sources)?  You specify the datasource as OLEDB, use the OLEDB Provider for SSAS, and you get more of a chance to write your own MDX.